# Current Step: Building Tasks.json File

Tags: c++, powershell, visual-studio-code, command-prompt, git-bash

I'm getting the error below while following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIw02CaEusY could someone help me figure out where I messed.

```
    {
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": ["-g", "main.cpp"],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

> Executing task: g++ -g main.cpp <
>
> 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file. The terminal process terminated with exit code:
>   1
>
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Comment: Install the GCC compiler at your computer.

Comment: I already have it installed  @πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: Apparently VS-code can't find it using your `PATH` variable settings then.

Answer (score 1):

See for instance [Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issue 1329](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1329#issuecomment-350901167):

> I've reproed the problem. I'm not sure why VS Code isn't picking the environment path or what path it's using, because it picks up my CMake directory somehow, but not my MinGW directory. I was able to fix this via using the full path to g++ in the command
>
> Change the command property to from "`g++`" to "`C:/MinGW/bin/g++`".